# How to repair cut/ripped convertible soft top?

Tags: mazda, miata

I have a Miata soft-top. The top was recently cut open overnight. I used a bit of epoxy to glue it back together (rain was coming). Is there some type of typical procedure/kits to repair this type of canvas? Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no *pretty* way to fix it other than replacement. I've seen people stitch it together, then put rubber cement on it to seal the crack. U-G-L-Y ... I got nothing beyond that.

Comment: Fiberglass resin or if you could stitch with fiberglass and use a little resin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've known friends repair soft top damage like this using a tent repair kit purchased from a camping shop.

These are pre-glued patches that cover the tear.  A lot less ugly than either stitching and gluing or gaffer tape.  Also, they stay stuck after the hood has been raised and lowered a few times.

They aren't perfect, you can still see the repair, but they work.

I would check that you get one suitable for a canvas tent, not one just for a nylon tent.

Comment: awesome! I've seen them for sale online, wasn't sure if that would be the way to go. Thanks for confirm, will give it a try!